# ALAsset NSURL *assetURL returns NULL

Tags: iphone, ios, alassetslibrary

I'm having a weird issue trying to save an image to my SavedPhotosAlbum using the ALAssetsLibrary, particularly when I'm using the writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum method.

Basically my issue is that the NSURL is returning null within my completion block... there is no Error, but the URL is null.

Here's the method :

```
UIImage *imageToSave = [libraryPicture imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];


  ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
  [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[imageToSave CGImage] orientation:ALAssetOrientationUp  completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {

  NSLog(@"AssetURL: %@", assetURL);

  if(!error) {
    NSLog(@"\t ! Error");
    NSLog(@"\t Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    NSLog(@"\t Error code %d", [error code]);
  }

  if(error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"\t ERROR != NIL");
    NSLog(@"\t Error - Image Failed To Save With Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    NSLog(@"\t Error code %d", [error code]);
  }

  if(error == nil) {
    NSLog(@"\t ERROR == NIL");
  }

  }];
```

I use a pretty similar method just a few lines away (in another switch case) that works, and it prints the URL within an almost identical completion block (though the called method differs):

```
[stillCamera capturePhotoAsJPEGProcessedUpToFilter:selectedFilter withCompletionHandler:^(NSData *processedJPEG, NSError *error) {
  ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
  [library writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:processedJPEG metadata:stillCamera.currentCaptureMetadata completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error2) {
    if (error2 != nil) {
      NSLog(@"ERROR: the image failed to be written");
    }
    else {
      NSLog(@"PHOTO SAVED FROM STILL CAMERA - assetURL: %@", assetURL);
    }

  }];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really are seeing the behaviour you state, this would appear to be the Asset Library breaking its API contract. You should file a radar with Apple with an example project that demonstrates this, and perhaps also file a DTS incident for a speedier response.